# Webview always return blank screen in ios Xamarin.Forms

Tags: ios, webview, xamarin.forms

I'm using this code sample to load a page with https protocol, but I'm unable to make it work: https://github.com/TheRealAdamKemp/AuthenticatedWebView

I'm using "https://www.google.com" as web page but nothing. I've also tried to add App Security Permission in Info.plist. I always get a blank page.

Can anyone explain to me why?

Comment: try to put url like this  "http://www.google.com"

Comment: Have you figured out the solution?

Comment: try to use http instead of https , another thing try to make WebView.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
           WebView.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;

Answer (score 4):

If you are responding to the WebView.Navigating event, be sure to not set its args.Cancel to true if the page loaded is the WevView.Source.  The iOS implementation of WebView.Navigating fires when the WebView.Source is loaded but the Android implementation does not.  If you set args.Cancel to true when the page in question is the WebView.Source, the WebView will be blank.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was stuck on this for ages :D

Answer (score 0):

you need to give permission for AppTransportSecurity(ATS). So that go to your info.plist and, add the permission. Note : inside a main dict tag paste given code

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
 <dict>  
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>  
 </dict>
```