# Webview on IOS does not allow Navigating=“WebView_Navigating”

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am using a webview to display html. The html contains external links so I have added `Navigating="WebView_Navigating"` to my webview and it is working perfectly on an Android **but IOS shows nothing where the converted html should be**. Whenever I remove `Navigating="WebView_Navigating"` from the webview, everything is correct in IOS but I need to be able to use external links.
What am I missing?

I have already added `[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(WebView), typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.WkWebViewRenderer))]` to my `AssemblyInfo.cs` file in the IOS project. I have also added NSAppTransportSecurity NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to my info.plist file.

Page:

```
 <ContentPage.Resources>
     <local1:HtmlConverter x:Key="HtmlConverter"/>
 </ContentPage.Resources>


    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout Padding="20" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Image Source="/images/guests_henry_1080x1080.jpeg"
              HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
              VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" />

            <WebView Navigating="WebView_Navigating" Source="{Binding Item.Text, Converter={StaticResource HtmlConverter}}" WidthRequest="1000" HeightRequest="1000" />

        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

Code:

    public partial class BioHenryPage : ContentPage
    {
        public BioHenryPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BioHenryViewModel viewModel = new BioHenryViewModel();

            BindingContext = viewModel;
        }

        public void WebView_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.Url.StartsWith("http"))
            {
                Device.OpenUri(new Uri(args.Url));
            }
            args.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

I expect the converted html to show in both Android and IOS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the **URL** of web in iOS, you can use **CustomRenderer** .

> in your iOS project

```
using xxx.iOS;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(WebView), typeof(myWebRender))]

namespace xxx.iOS
{
    class myWebRender : WebViewRenderer
    {

        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement == null)
            {   // perform initial setup
                UIWebView myWebView = (UIWebView)this.NativeView;

                myWebView.Delegate = new CustomWebViewDelegate();
            }
        }

        public class CustomWebViewDelegate : UIWebViewDelegate
        {
            public CustomWebViewDelegate()
            {
            }

            public override bool ShouldStartLoad(UIWebView webView, NSUrlRequest request, UIWebViewNavigationType navigationType)
            {


                string url = request.Url.AbsoluteString;

                if(url.StartsWith("http"))
                {
                    if(UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl(request.Url))
                    {
                        UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(request.Url);
                    }
                }


                webView.EvaluateJavascript("window.stop();");

                return true;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lucas, thank you so much for your answer! My solution was to move the webview navigating to the end of the constructor after binding. It was a timing issue with iOS. This is where I found the solution. [Webview always return blank screen in ios Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41801755/webview-always-return-blank-screen-in-ios-xamarin-forms)

"If you are responding to the WebView.Navigating event, be sure to not set its args.Cancel to true if the page loaded is the WevView.Source. The iOS implementation of WebView.Navigating fires when the WebView.Source is loaded but the Android implementation does not. If you set args.Cancel to true when the page in question is the WebView.Source, the WebView will be blank."